# Gráfico con chart.js que respete la escala temporal

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, apex-chart

tengo un gráfico de líneas con chart.js, pero necesito que la distancia entre las fechas del eje x sean reales, quiero decir, tengo la misma distancia entre las 12:00 y las 12:30 que entre las 13:00 y las 14:30, y necesito que la distancia que haya sea relacional, es decir no puede haber el mismo espacio entre dos puntos con 30minutos de diferencia, que entre 2 puntos con 2 horas de diferencia, mi código es este:

```
 var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
 
            var labels = ['10:20', '10:25', '11:00', '11:30', '13:00', '13:10'];
            var values = [0, 10, 5, 2, 10, 5];
 
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line', 
                data: {
                    labels: labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: values,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                        ]
                    }]
                }, 
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        y: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }],
                        x: {
                            type: 'time',
                            time: { 
                                tooltipFormat: 'hour'
                            },
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

y mi gráfico se ve tal que así:
[image: grafico con chart.js]

alguien sabe como puedo poner que la distancia entre los labels del eje x sean relacionadas con el tiempo? si no es con chart.js, alguien conoce alguna otra librería que permita esto? estoy usando Angular para el frontend

Comment: no se si existe alguna caracteristica para eso  pero yo meteria los labels como describes y trataria de cuadrar con los valores

Comment: al final he podido con morris.js

Comment: Debes de crear los valores dentro de esos rangos como describe @NicolasOñate. Veo dos opciones, que se queden en blanco ( 0 ), o que promedies la distancia, aunque esto ultimo cambiaria mucho la forma de la gráfica.

Answer (score 1):

Para que el eje del tiempo te quede escalado, debes pasarle a `chart.js` los labels de tipo fecha. Puedes hacerlo utilizando `moment.js`.

Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var labels = ['10:20', '10:25', '11:00', '11:30', '13:00', '13:10'];
var values = [0, 10, 5, 2, 10, 5];
labels = labels.map(e => {
    let [hora, min] = e.split(':')
    const m = moment({hour: hora, minute: min });
    return m
});
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: "# of Votes",
            data: values,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    displayFormats: {
                        'hour': 'HH:MM',
                    },
                    tooltipFormat: 'HH:MM'
                },       
                 ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 5,
                    maxRotation: 0,
                    minRotation: 0
                  }
            }],
        },
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```